# Handling inheritance when different types of objects need a different method signature

Tags: java, spring, inheritance

Below is my specific example, but this is a more a general question on how to handle different signatures required for subclasses.

I have page objects that represent different web pages on a site. They are all something that is navigable through the site, so I thought it would make sense that they could inherit a class called navigable. I am trying to make it so that you can add a page object (using spring so you can just autowire it in), and then call navigate and it will get you to the page. Now this is something I have figured out a way to do, but the problem arises that some pages need an argument for the row so that you would have to use a signature like: navigate(String rowDescription) to get to the page.

Most pages have no rows on them so it doesn't make sense for them to have that method, some pages have both a path from a row, and also a path that doesn't require a row. What I have right now works, but sort of breaks some of the rules of inheritance. Here is the gist of what I have in pseudo-java code:

```
// where T is the current page, and P is the previous.
public abstract class Navigable<T,P extends Navigable>{

    public abstract T navigate();

    protected P resolvePreviousPage(){
      // spring magic to get previous page object
    }

    public T navigate(String rowDescription){
       throw unimplementedException(); // Something that has a row would have to override this.
    }

    public navigateBack(){
      //Default way of navigating back a page;    
    }
}
```

Then a page object would extend Navigable and implement navigate in some form like this:

```
public thisPageObject navigate(){
  return resolvePreviousPage().navigate()
   .linkToGetToThisPage.click; // Clicking this link returns this page
}
```

Maybe inheritance is not the best way to tackle this problem, could I get a suggestion on a good way of handling this?

Comment: What about using interfaces?

Comment: I don't see a clear solution how that would help, you mind elaborating on that?

Comment: the question is not clear. This doesn't help "class Navigable<T,P extends Navigable>{". I can't see the problem. What you need is an object that represents a node in a structure (list, tree) ?

Comment: I figured out a way to do it. For some reason I was stuck in the mind set that i could only access the navigate method if Navigable contained that method, but I am now just having subclasses have either navigate() or navigate(String row desc). Basically just had to add another layer to the inheritance tree.